# Using greater than expression to filter text file lines?

Tags: python

I have a text file with multiple lines and want to find which lines have values greater than 85%.

```
'workdata worka worka1 size 84% total'
'workdata workb workb1 size 89% total'
'workdata workc workc1 size 63% total'
'workdata workd workd1 size 94% total'
```

Can someone please show how I can get just the sentences with 85% or more in the fifth column?

Comment: Where did you get stuck in your attempt?

Comment: You'll want to write a regular expression to pull out the number.  I'd suggest checking out these resources: [regex tutorial](http://regexr.com/), [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Use a regex (via [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)) to extract the digits before the `%`. convert them to an integer and see if it is greater than 85.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the percentage will always be in the 5th column, then just split each row on space, remove the percentage sign, and turn it into a float. Something like this:

```
lines = open("fileName", "r").read().splitlines()
for row in lines:
    if float(row.split()[4].replace("%",""))>85:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract percent first, and then filter the lines basing on that.

```
import re

def extract_percent(line):
    # doing extraction
    try:
        return int(re.findall('[0-9]+%', line)[0][:-1])
    except:
        return 0

print [line for line in lines if extract_percent(line) > 85]
```

If nothing is found, 0 is returned.
Otherwise is returned the number before `%`.
If you have several percent numbers in the string, the first one is returned.

It can become a little bit trickier if the percent can be float,
but it is not so hard also. Just play with the regular expression `[0-9]+%`.

If the position is fixed (fifth column), you can rewrite the `extract_percent` function this way:

```
def extract_percent(line):
    try:
        return int(line.split()[4][:-1])
    except:
        return 0
```

Comment: You're only encouraging poor question like this...and your indention does not follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), so it's not even that great of an example.

Comment: @martineau: Thank you for the tip! Indentation is fixed now.

Comment: the percent is always in the same position, so the :-1 will work. It is stopping at the first match item, returning 84. I think I may not be reading the file in at the right spot, or not looping through it...

Comment: @mustang: Using a regular expression is more robust and less likely to break due to small variations in input.